# Loop to show progress of success

Tags: r, loops

I work on evaluation of stock portfolio for my diploma thesis and I cannot go trough this loop yet. I have this example data

```
Profit<-runif(20,min=-3,max=3)
df<-data.frame(Profit=Profit)
```

The frame looks like

```
       Profit
1   2.8708201
2  -1.7154991
3  -2.7206445
4   1.2499062
5  -1.1219258
6   1.3467217
7   0.3062028
8  -1.9457253
9   0.3397503
10  2.7755952
11  2.8754588
12  2.6819872
13 -0.7348086
14  2.5866392
15  1.4387628
16 -1.7970749
17 -1.2338479
18  2.7091911
19  0.4001345
20  2.5101570
```

and these are Profits for concrete trades in percentage. All I need to do is join another column where will be progress of investments.
Lets say I have

```
startcash<-100000
```

And I need to create loop which will work like

```
 Progress[1]<-startcash + ((startcash*Profit[1])/100) 
 Progress[2]<-Progress[1] + ((Progress[1]*Profit[2])/100)
```

and so on. Then I will just join columns like

```
cbind(df,Progress)
```

and that is all.
I have tried something like this

```
startcash=100000
DF<-data.frame()
i=1
while (i <nrow(newDF)) {
  Progress<-startcash + ((startcash*Profit[i])/100)
  DF<-data.frame(Progress)
  startcash<-Progress
  i=i+1
  }
```

but it gives nonsense and I am still learning in loop area so any advice is aprreciated.
Any straighforward way how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the second column in the `data.frame` without any data using the column name and assigning `NA`s to every row like this. This will make the next few steps easier.

```
Profit <- runif(20, min=-3, max=3)
df <- data.frame(Profit=Profit, Progress = NA)
```

Now using the use the elements from the `data.frame` within the calculations

```
startcash<-100000

df$Progress[1] <- startcash + ( (startcash * df$Profit[1])/100) 
df$Progress[2] <- df$Progress[1] + ( (df$Progress[1] * df$Profit[2])/100)
head(df)
```

Below is the example using a `while` loop. But these are dangerous, and sometimes never end.

```
startcash=100000

i=1
while (i <= nrow(df) ) {
  df$Progress[i] <- startcash + ( (startcash * df$Profit[i])/100) 
  startcash <- df$Progress[i]
  i=i+1
}
```

I prefer to use `for` loops because I know they will safely come to an end.

```
startcash=100000

for(i in 1:nrow(df) ){
  df$Progress[i] <- startcash + ( (startcash * df$Profit[i])/100) 
  startcash <- df$Progress[i]
}
```

This should do you what you need it to do.

Comment: Thank you, it works well and now I understand loops a bit more.